# MutationObserver won't trigger in user script on attribute change - any ideas?

Tags: javascript, attributes, mutation-observers

Ok so I have the following user script(tampermonkey):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Allow only multiples
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  observe and remove multiples
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.bet365.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(async function loop() {
     try{
         const betsipframe = window.getBetslipFrame.bind(window)
         const element = betsipframe().bsFrame.getElement().contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("betSlip")[0];

        (new MutationObserver(mutations => console.log(mutations))).observe(element, {attributes: true,
                                                                                      attributeFilter: ["data-restrictedmultiples"]})
         }
    catch(error){console.log(error), setTimeout(loop,89)}
})()
```

It's basically looping until no error occurs (which means the host page has fully loaded) and then it creates an attribute observer. However the attribute observer never gets executed nevertheless the "data-restrictedmultiples" on the betslip changes.

I don't know can the page scripts have some anti-tamper measures. (I've searched MutationObserver inside them but have not found anything matching.)

Comment: Hard to help without a [mcve]

Comment: Have you verified that the element registered to your `MutationObserver` is valid  on registration? Maybe the registration is performed when the element it still not present in page

Comment: 1) Try to use the frame's observer constructor: new betsipframe().bsFrame.getElement().contentWindow.MutationObserver, 2) It's possible the mutation is performed by replacing a larger tree that includes the parent element(s) so try to observe the entire document first (with subtree:true, childList:true) to see the exact sequence.

Comment: Is `catch()` ever reached? Is `console.log(error), setTimeout(loop,89)` within `catch` block valid syntax? Why is `async` used?

Comment: What does `console.log(element)` output?

Comment: @guest271314 The element in html.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `async`, `try..catch` and `setTimeout` do not appear to be necessary

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue at plnkr https://plnkr.co?

Comment: @wOxxOm I think observing the whole document is the right track. It spits out attribute changes on everything including my target.